# lockResource() returns a pointer but to an unknown struct

Tags: windows, winapi, visual-c++

I'm working with visual studio 2003 on Windows 7.

I'm trying to embed a binary file into a windows console application (c++).
I added into the resource script (.rc file) the following line:

```
SampleFile RCDATA  "c:\\sample.zip"
```

and also added the following code to access the file:

```
HRSRC hResource = FindResource(NULL, (LPCSTR)"SampleFile", RT_RCDATA);
LPVOID l = LockResource(hResource);
```

now, hResource is a valid handle and LockResource also succeeds but the pointer l points to some struct, probably a header, that is followed by the actual data of the zip file I was trying to embed.
I managed to spot that the second DWORD in the said header is the size of the file, and the name of the resource ("SampleFile") also appears in the header, but couldn't manage to find a description of the header or at least the header size.

Comment: You need to do FindResource(), **LoadResource()**, then LockResource().

Comment: To expand on this, I beleive `LockResource()` is a almost a no-op on Win32. Due to [historical reasons](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/02/02/66159.aspx) it used to lock a movable memory block on <Win32 but that is no longer required.

Answer (score 4):

As Luke said, You're missing a `LoadResource()` call in the middle.

`FindResource()` essentially gives you a pointer/handle to the resource header, `LoadResource()` reads that header and gives you a value that (on win32) points to the data itself, but used to be an HGlobal that could be moved in memory. You would then lock this location and get a pointer using `LockResource()`.

The usage stays the same on Win32 though.

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648047.aspx)

> Do not try to lock a resource by using the handle returned by the FindResource or FindResourceEx function. Such a handle points to random data.

The resource header is described in MSDN as the fictional [`RESOURCEHEADER`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648027.aspx) structure.

This reply is largely taken from Raymond Chen's article on [16-bit resource management](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/02/02/66159.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You have an Api function to get size of resource [SizeofResource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648048%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).
The pointer points to the beginning of the file added as resource (in your case "c:\sample.zip). 
If you want you can pass that pointer to a uncompress library or simply write to disk.

Comment: I am aware of the SizeOfResource function. However, as I said in my question, the pointer the is returned by LockResource DOES NOT point to the data in the file. It points to some struct. It's like that with any file type, not only .zip files.

Comment: Miss-read the question. There is no internal header. Try to open the file in ResHacker and make sure you have in resources what you want. Then make sure you use MAKEINTRESOURCE, the name ((LPCSTR)"SampleFile") isn't stored in the executable. I don't see how `FindResource` succeeded.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the help.
Actually I did have LoadResource in my code, which got lost in the copy paste to the site.
However, that is related to the problem in my code.
The code looked like this: (Psuedo code this time)
HANDLE hFindHandle = FindResource(...);
LoadResource(hFindHandle and Module Handle);
and then
LPVOID l = LockResource(hFindHandle);

I didn't use the returned value from the LoadResource but kept using the one from the FindResource, so even though I did call LoadResource, I didn't get the correct pointer from LockResource.

Comment: Which is exactly why you should copy and paste your exact code rather than an edited subset/snippet of it.